# How to secure SSH agent forwarding on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh

I'm trying to configure ssh agent forwarding. The workstation that starts the connection is a Windows, the intermediate and second hosts are Linux.

On Windows, I managed to make it work using PageAnt. But I don't like the fact that once a key is loaded, there is no way to lock it and force a user to re-enter his password after a few seconds for instance.

So I tried to open the private key using Putty (Menu "Connection - SSH - Auth"), without PageAnt. This would be a good way to do it because you have to enter the passphrase of the key each time you open a connection. But then agent forwarding doesn't work anymore.

Anyone would have an idea on how to make it work correctly? The main idea is to use agent forwarding from Windows workstations that wouldn't be turned into opened gateways to the servers if a user doesn't lock its station for instance.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I store my SSH keys in a [Keepass](http://keepass.info/) database and use a [key agent extension](http://keepass.info/plugins.html#keeagent) to provide it to Putty and other clients.

The keepass program is configured to lock itself after a few seconds of inactivity and unlocking it will require the user to enter their password.